# How to xfade an accelerated stream into a stream of unchanged speed

Tags: ffmpeg

How to `xfade` one stream, that was speed up with `setpts` into another stream using ffmpeg?

The natural approach would be:

```
ffmpeg
 -i a.mkv
 -i b.mkv
 -filter_complex "
   [0:v]setpts=0.2*(PTS-STARTPTS)[A_OUT];
   [A_OUT][1:v]xfade=duration=2:offset=10[out]" 
 -map '[out]'
 out.mkv
```

but this always results in a 5x speed up of the second stream during the 2sec transition time of xfade. In other words, during xfade, the PTS definition of the first stream is used for the second stream.

Comment: Add the fps filter with source_fps after setpts to fill in the vacant time slots created by setpts.

Answer (score 0):

As Gyan statet, the solution would be to add the `fps` filter to set source frame rate to the accelerated stream and also set the original time base with `settb` for both streams.

The original example would look like:

```
ffmpeg
 -i a.mkv
 -i b.mkv
 -filter_complex "
   [0:v]setpts=0.2*(PTS-STARTPTS),fps=fps=source_fps,settb=AVTB[A_OUT];
   [1:v]settb=AVTB[B_OUT];
   [A_OUT][B_OUT]xfade=duration=2:offset=10[out]" 
 -map '[out]'
 out.mkv
```